# Reactive native - Unable to start iOS and android simultor , Error routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:

Tags: android, ios

Already i worked on Reactive Native and can able to start android and iOS emulator , recently changed my office laptop and getting the below error on both iOS and android when running npm start / npm run ios / npm run android command

```
Error running adb: write EPROTO 140736242836288:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:

Error: write EPROTO 140736242836288:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:



Initially i thought it would be my company proxy setting so i setting npm config to set proxy so still getting the error 

Below is my package.json :
{
  "name": "CDD",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0"
  }
}
```

Please help me to start android / ios emulator

Comment: Work around solved this issue : i installed expo client ( https://expo.io/ ) then its starting working , i checked the react native code : node_modules/xdl/build/android.js for identifying this issue ,  Welcome any comment on my solution